# How to list all open Excel workbooks

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm writing a c# console app with .net 4.7.1. I have several open Excel workbooks on my computer. I am trying to list all of the open Excel workbooks on my computer.

I've looked at several SO posts and have put this code together that should list all of the open Excel workbooks on my computer but when I run the code
none of the open Excel workbooks get listed.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelWorkbooks
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            oXL = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            Console.WriteLine("starting");
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook blah in oXL.Workbooks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(blah.Name.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("ending");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

the output should be

> starting
>
> there should be a list of open Excel workbooks here
>
> ending

but instead this is what is output

> starting
>
> ending

If someone could point me in the right direction of what needs to be added/subtracted or changed in my code so it will list all of the open Excel workbooks on my computer I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I was playing around with this and I closed the 2 Excel workbooks that were open. I then looked in the task manager and saw that even after I closed all of the Excel workbooks there were like 10 "EXCEL" processes still running. I closed all of "EXCEL" processes and then opened the 2 Excel workbooks again. Now the code above lists the 2 open Excel workbooks. So, I guess the question has changed somewhat to why were there 10 "EXCEL" processes running when I only had 2 open workbooks and more importantly going forward how should I deal with this so if there are additional "EXCEL" processes I can handle this so it will show the open Excel workbooks. Thanks.

Comment: `Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            oXL = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");` Why are you setting `oXL` twice? What do you think `new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()` does?

Comment: Regarding your second question (multiple instances of Excel), you're not properly cleaning up the multiple instances you create with the two separate settings of `oXL` that @mjwills mentions. Fix the logic errors in your code so that you're retrieving the open instance rather than creating a new one and discarding it first - the ones you're throwing away don't get closed, because you don't close them before tossing them aside.

Comment: To clarify, `new` starts a new instance of Excel; it does not get the active one. You then grab another reference of that just-started instance, throwing away the reference you already have after `new`. That new instance doesn't have open workbooks, so you get an empty list. If you close your app and then look at Task Manager, you'll have two copies of Excel. Run your code again, close it, and look at Task Manager, and you'll have another open copy of Excel. Repeat, and watch the number of Excel processes continue to increase.

Comment: Your code works for me. Please check if there is assembly version mismatch.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for the insight, I had no idea that was what is causing that. As I stated in my EDIT I was able to list the open workbooks after I killed all the extra instances of the Excel process and I believe that this is the issue that was preventing me from my code doing what I wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to list the current Excel instance workbooks names, just change:

```
Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
oXL = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

to:

```
 Application oXL = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

you may want to add some Try/Catch block to handle the case of no Excel instance available

Comment: Any idea why the `oXL.Workbooks.Count` = `0` when the opened excel workbook is in protected view?